# How to reduce/decrease Application storage and Build-in-memory storage of Blackberry Simulator?

Tags: testing, mobile, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

How to reduce/decrease Application-storage and Build-in-memory storage of Blackberry Simulator?

As I need it to test my Blackberry Apps behaviour on low memory. I am using Blackberry simulator 9860.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the eclipse plugin, you can go to `Run configurations -> Simulator tab -> Memory tab` and play with the values in heap size field and SDCard size. Never tried so I can't tell if it works.

---

UPDATE:
If you are using the simulator alone, you can change options from command line. Open the simulator directory in a command line shell. There's an application there called `fledge.exe`. To change heap size, type:

```
fledge /heap-size={<size in bytes>}
```

The default heap value is 94.68 MB.

For more info about what memory settings you can change, type "`fledge /help`" and click in the "memory" section in the dialog.

Comment: I am not using any IDE. I have installed simulator application standalone.